# What is the best way to get all photos from a facebook page including the comments and likes using facebook sdk in android?

Tags: android, facebook, performance, facebook-graph-api, sdk

using the graph API, I can very well make a query like this :
{facebook-page-id}/photos?type=uploaded

This question has to be more on the theoretical side.
I'm working on an android application that has to show the images(uploaded photos) from a particular facebook page. Now, I can access all the pictures using the graph API and the queries.
My question is regarding the feasibility of this approach. Do I have any other method that is better than this, given the limit that facebook puts on requests generating from a single device with a single token.
Although Graph API can easily do that, is there any other approach to it ?

Comment: get it from the page source...p

Comment: But then, it should be dynamic and I can't hardcode it.

Comment: from the page source? scraping is not allowed.

Comment: I'm only left with graph API right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your only option (on any platform) will be to use Graph API.

What you are describing sounds like a form of page management app, which is not necessarily something that makes a lot of sense on a mobile device. The reason is that the number of requests required to fetch the information you are requesting can easily become enormous.

When doing this in a web application, you can leverage a web server's virtually infinite storage capacity and bandwidth (compared to a mobile device), and you can even reduce the amount of Graph API requests by implementing [RTUs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.4). The latter is impossible on a mobile device, as you need a live web endpoint capable of receiving RTU callbacks from Facebook.

Comment: I needed to perform simple operations like getting all the posts along with their likes. I suppose, passing a single query is considered as 'one' request; correct me if I'm wrong, even though it's getting somewhere around 20-25 jsonobjects.

Comment: You can use [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/batch-requests/), but designing one batch request in such a way that it's inner requests all and their inter-dependencies are constructed properly is certainly going to be difficult. And since such a request will still return a huge amount of data, doing this on a mobile device is not exactly recommended, in my opinion.